# generate non-consecutive samples

Tags: matlab, random

How can we efficiently generate `k` random and **non-consecutive** samples out of `[1,...,N]`?

Non-desired Example with `(N=10, k=4)`:
`2,3,8,10`

This is not a desired example since `2` and `3` are consecutive.

Desired Example with `(N=10, k=4)`:
`2,6,8,10`

This is a good example since the difference between every pair of samples is greater than `1`

Comment: import random
random.sample(["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"],4)
I think it works for what you want.

Comment: @ysearka : is it guaranteed that samples are not consecutive?

Comment: Define "non-consecutive".  Do you mean that for any value in the output, there shouldn't be an index one above, or one below?

Comment: No, of course it doesn't guarantee that; **it's random**.

Comment: By "not consecutive" do you mean not consecutive as they appear in the output e.g. `[5,3,1,4]` would be ok? Or do you mean that none of the samples should be within 1 of any other sample?

Comment: @rayryeng : I have put 2 examples in the question to show what I mean by non-consecutive.

Comment: That example is unclear, which is why I asked you again.

Comment: @A.M. The two examples are not enough to clarify your requirement

Comment: how come it's random then?

Comment: @rayryeng : sorry for being not clear. I mean if for example `2` is chosen, then we would not pick up either `1` or `3` as the next choice because they are neighbor with `2`.

Comment: @A.M. - Given the activity in the comments thread of your question, you should probably take that as a hint that your question is ill-posed.  Please consider adding more information.

Comment: @A.M. - Ah. OK great.  That's what I thought.  You tagged both Python and MATLAB.  Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @ThePredator: It is possible for something to be randomly generated yet satisfy constraints. The OP hasn't asked for a particular distribution, and there may be more than one answer here with slightly different distributions depending on how it is generated.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Understood!

Comment: @rayryeng : I prefer MATLAB.

Comment: @NeilSlater - I think what the OP intends is that once we select.... for example... 2... then 1 and 3 are not allowed to be selected anymore.  I can't see how this can be done without resulting in an iterative approach.

Comment: @NeilSlater : If you sort them, they would be consecutive. I have edited the question and wrote that **difference between every pair of samples is greater than 1**.

Comment: @A.M. - That's **after** you sort them, right?

Comment: @rayryeng: conceptually yes but when we say **every pair** of samples, it implies that.

Comment: @A.M.  In your question you say "random". You probably mean _random with uniform distribution (all possible outputs equally likely)_. You should specify that in the question

Comment: @LuisMendo: Thanks for pointing that out but I guess because of the constraint we are putting on the problem, we cannot have uniform distribution.

Comment: @A.M. Of course we can. "Uniform" means all values _that satisfy the constraint_ are equally likely (which is probably what you want). And if it's not uniform, you should specify which distribution you want. Saying you want "random" samples is not enough

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sort(randperm(N-(k-1),k))+[0:(k-1)]
```

There is a simple obersavation behind this solution, if you take any sorted solution to your problem and substract `[0:(k-1)]`, you end up with a random choice of k numbers out of `N-(k-1)`

Comment: By the way, in python:  `map(operator.add, sorted(random.sample(range(1,N-k+2),k)),range(0,k))`

Comment: @Daniel Well thought!

Comment: With `numpy`: `sorted(numpy.random.choice(N-(k-1), k, replace=False)) + numpy.arange(k) + 1`. Without: `[x + i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(sorted(random.sample(range(N-(k-1)), k)))]`.

Comment: In essence, take a random strictly increasing sequence, and add 1 to the gap between each number. The minimum gap is now 2, preventing consecutive numbers.

Comment: This only works if the OP wanted a random permutation of the entire input set.  Many of the other solutions assume a random selection of ` n<M` elements of the set.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: That's right, I totally skipped the discussion what QA exactly whats because Luis Mendo's answer was already accepted when I wrote this. Assumed this is what is wanted, so I just provided a more efficient version of it.

Comment: @Daniel - I've made a chat room for us MATLAB folks: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - Come and visit whenever you're free!

Answer (score 4):

Let *S* denote the set of all `k`-element vectors with values taken from `[1,...,N]` that don't have any consecutive values. To randomly sample with a **uniform** distribution over *S*, you can use a rejection method:

1. Sample uniformly on a larger sample space, *T*.
2. If the sample belongs to the target region *S*, accept the sample. Else return to step 1 (the sample is rejected).

In Matlab, it's easy to generate uniformly distributed `k`-element vectors with values taken from `[1,...,N]` without replacement (function [`randsample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html)). So this is used as the sample space *T*:

```matlab
k = 4;
N = 10;
result = [1 1];                         % // just to get while loop started
while any(diff(result)<=1)              % // does not meet condition: try again
    result = sort(randsample(N, k).');  %'// random sample without replacement
end
```

Comment: The advantage of simple approach and even distribution is nice, but this will suffer from poor performance with moderately large k, especially when getting close to the limits of k for any particular N.

Comment: Indeed. This can be very inefficient for high N and K=(N+1)/2

Comment: Agreed. Rejection method may be inefficient

Comment: If you don't find a nice trick (see my answer), rejection is the only possibility for such problems. Most other answers I saw here try to create the solution element by element, resulting in slightly different probabilities for the different solutions.

Answer (score 3):

A Python class which correctly checks every pair of samples.  You're responsible for not passing it a set of numbers that is impossible, though (like N = 10, k = 100).

```
>>> class NonConsecutiveSampler(object):
        def __init__(self,N):
                import random
                self.num = N
        def get_samples(self,k):
                possibilities = [i for i in range(1,self.num + 1)]
                samples = []
                while len(samples) < k:
                        r = random.sample(possibilities,1)[0]
                        samples.append(r)
                        for i in range(r - 1, r + 2):
                                if i in possibilities:
                                        possibilities.remove(i)
                samples.sort()
                return samples


>>> n = NonConsecutiveSampler(10)
>>> n.get_samples(4)
[2, 5, 8, 10]
>>> n.get_samples(4)
[1, 5, 7, 10]
>>> n.get_samples(4)
[3, 6, 8, 10]
>>> n.get_samples(4)
[1, 3, 5, 8]
```

**EDIT**:  Made it *much* more efficient

Comment: There is a possibility that this algorithm get's stuck. For N=3, k=2 the only solution is [1,3]. If by bad luck 2 is picked first, a solution can't be found.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the increment between samples evenly distributed between 2 and N-1 (to avoid consecutive and repeated numbers):

```
N=10;
k=4;
increments = floor(rand(1,k)*(N-2))+2  %// increments allowed are from 2 to N-1 inclusive
out = mod(cumsum(increments), N)+1   %// sum increments
```

Same in python:

```
from numpy import cumsum, floor, mod, random
N=5
k=100
increments = floor(random.rand(1,k)*(N-2))+2
out = mod(cumsum(increments), N)+1
print(out)

[ 5.  3.  1.  5.  2.  4.  3.  2.  4.  2.  4.  3.  1.  5.  4.  3.  5.  4.
  2.  5.  4.  2.  5.  2.  4.  1.  5.  4.  1.  5.  3.  1.  3.  2.  4.  1.
  5.  4.  1.  3.  5.  4.  3.  5.  2.  1.  3.  2.  4.  3.  1.  4.  2.  1.
  3.  2.  1.  4.  3.  2.  1.  3.  5.  3.  5.  4.  2.  4.  2.  1.  3.  2.
  1.  3.  5.  2.  5.  4.  3.  1.  4.  1.  4.  3.  5.  4.  2.  1.  5.  2.
  1.  5.  4.  2.  4.  3.  5.  2.  4.  1.]
```

Over 100 iterations, even if I limit the number to 1..5, there is no repeated/consecutive number.

Comment: `mod` function generates repetitive samples!

Comment: Yes, but repetitive is not consecutive. If you don't want repetitive, then make the increment from 2 to N-1.

Comment: I have faced counter-examples with your method. still both consecutive samples and repetitive samples.

Comment: I do not get any consecutive number. I edited the increment to also discard repeated numbers.

Comment: Thanks. When I run the edited code, I do not get consecutive samples but still I get repetitive samples which I guess could be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in MATLAB (perhaps inelegant) could be something like this:

```
N = 10;
k = 4;
out = zeros(1,k);

vec = 1 : N;

for idx = 1 : k
    ind = randi(numel(vec), 1);
    left = max(ind-1, 1); right = min(numel(vec), ind+1);
    out(idx) = vec(ind);
    to_remove = ind;
    if vec(left) == vec(ind)-1 
        to_remove = [to_remove left];
    end
    if vec(right) == vec(ind)+1
        to_remove = [to_remove right];
    end
    vec(to_remove) = [];
end
```

We first declare `N` and `k`, then declare an output array of zeroes that is `k` long.  We then generate a sampling vector `vec` that goes from 1 up to as `N` initially.  Next, for each value we want to place into the output, we generate a random position to sample from the vector, then take a look at the position from the left and from the right... ensuring that we are within the boundaries of the array.  Also, we **only** remove to the left or right if the value at the left of the index to remove and also the right are equal to each other (thanks beaker!)

We use this location and sample from this vector, place the value at this location to the output, then remove the indices in this vector that are to the left, to the right, and the actual index itself from this vector.  This removes the possibility of sampling from those values again.  We repeat this until we run out of values to place in the output.

Here are a few of trial runs:

```
>> out

out =

     9     7     1     5

>> out

out =

     7     1     4    10

>> out

out =

    10     8     1     6

>> out

out =

    10     4     8     1
```

Comment: I can see a problem here, with `vec([left ind right]) = [];` you may end up removing non-consecutive elements from the sampling array. E.g. if the first sample is `5`, you remove 4,5,6 . . . but then the next sample is `3` you remove 2,3,7! So technically it meets the constraints, but it cannot generate many of the possible solutions.

Comment: @NeilSlater - Oh how true....alright.  I'll have to think about that.  Thanks for the spot.

Comment: @NeilSlater I figured out how to fix it. Will just need a couple of if statements but I'll fix it later tonight. Can't do it right now!

Comment: All you have to do is make sure that `vec(left) == vec(ind)-1` and `vec(right) == vec(ind)+1` before removing.

Comment: @beaker modified. Thanks!

Comment: Cool beans... though I think you had the idea already. Our comments posted at the same time. :)

Comment: @beaker - I've created a chat room for us MATLAB folks: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab - Come and visit whenever you're free!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's faster and easier to generate more samples than you need and then throw away the undesireable values.

One (slow) example.

```
vec= randi(100,1,1);
for j = 2:50,
   while(abs(vec(j)-vec(j-1)<2) vec(j)= randi(100,1,1);end;
end
```

Another way. Suppose you want 50 samples

```
vec = rand(100,100,1);
badindex = find(abs(vec(1:99)-vec(2:100) < 1));
vec(badindex) = vec(badindex-1)+vec(badindex+1);
% if you don't want big values,
vec(vec>100) = vec (vec>100) -100; % to ensure, I hope, that neighbors
```

% are nonconsecutive
(This would be easier in `R`) .

Comment: Plus 1 - Definitely easier in R.

Answer (score 1):

A not-particularly-elegant python solution:

```
def nonseq(n, k):
    out = [random.randint(0, n)]
    while len(out) < k:
        x = random.randint(0, n)
        if abs(x - out[-1]) > 1:
            out.append(x)
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

```
def ncsample(population, k):
    import random
    if k > 0:
        i = random.randrange(0, len(population) - 2*(k-1))
        return [population[i]] + ncsample(population[i+2:], k-1)
    else:
        return []
```

Note: it randomly finds the sequence in one shot (no rejection sampling in a while loop).

MATLAB implementation:

```
function r = ncsample(population, k)
    if k > 0
        i = randi(length(population) - 2*(k-1));
        r = [population(i) ncsample(population((i+2):end), k-1)];
    else
        r = [];
    end
end
```

Some tests:

```
>> for i=1:10; fprintf('%s\n',sprintf('%d ', ncsample(1:10, 4))); end
1 5 7 9 
3 5 8 10 
3 5 8 10 
4 6 8 10 
2 6 8 10 
1 4 8 10 
1 4 7 9 
3 6 8 10 
1 6 8 10 
2 4 7 9
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive elegant version, I just added a check on k and N to avoid infinite recursion, if k>N/2 no solution exists.

The result is guaranteed random.

```
import random

def myFunc(N,k):
    if k>(N+1)/2:
        return "k to big for N"
    returnValue = sorted(random.sample(range(1,N+1),k))
    toTest = [x - returnValue[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(returnValue)][1:]
    if 1 in toTest:
        return myFunc(N,k)
    else:
        return returnValue

print myFunc(10,4)
```

Comment: This code rejects N=3, k=2, but [1,3] is a solution. I think it is impossible if `k>(N+1)/2`

Comment: My bad, in any case the top answer is way better, I will correct it anyway.